# Which field launches an onchange of 2 fields

Tags: python, odoo, onchange, odoo-8

I have an onchange of two fields that is launched when modifying one of them.

```
@api.onchange('name', 'address')
def onchange_name_address(self):
**function code**
```

I would like to know when it comes into the function of that onchange which field is exactly the one that has launched it, if it has been 'name' or has been 'address'

Is there any way to know it? Thanks in advance

Comment: What I did in old API was to add a context to the XML fields (for example: `<field name="address" context="{'onchange_address': True}"/>` and `<field name="name" context="{'onchange_name': True}"/>`). Then, in the first line of the onchange method, check if the context brings the variables `onchange_address` or `onchange_name` or both of them. That told you which field triggered the onchange method. But, I am not sure if this still works in new API.